# sum of columns imported with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

I have two columns that will import some numbers (ajax) that change every second.

It is possible to display the sum of each column in "normal webpage" not on server side?

like:

```
line 1 -  95.20 Kwh   0.41 A
line 2 -   0.02 Kwh   0.02 A
line 3 - 230.20 Kwh   0.95 A

Total   325.42 Kwh 1.38 A
```

The numbers are printed with `<span class="analog"> ... </span>`

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible. If you'd like some more detailed help, then we need to see your HTML and JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select class names for tds that are in a column. For example

```
<tr>
<td>line 1</td>
<td class="kwa">92.20 kwh</td>
<td class="tdA">0.41 A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>line 2</td>
<td class="kwa">0.02 kwh</td>
<td class="tdA">0.02 A</td>
</tr>
```

Now jquery:

```
var sumKwa =0;
var sumA = 0;
$('td.kwa').each(function(){
   var num = $(this).html().split(' ')[0];
   sumKwa += parseFloat(num);
});
$('td.tdA').each(function(){
   var num = $(this).html().split(' ')[0];
   sumA += parseFloat(num);
});
```

And one thing: Ajax request in every 1 seconds is very heavy if users number is much. Instead of this it is better you to using javascript EvntSource that is for live connections.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your help.
The numbers on site are already imported with xml/ajax and they are updated every second. Thts why I cannot manage to sum them right away. I will try to learn about javascript EvntSource, but will be more easier with an example...

Here is how i import the numbers.

```
`https://jsbin.com/jayutoq/edit?html,js,output`
```